# Python import in a 3d environment an STL file

Tags: python, 3d, kivy

I'm facing like beginner Python language because I need to develop a desktop app to do develop a **slicer** for our binder jetting 3d printer. The outcome of the slicer must be in images and of course I need a **3d environment** where I can move or scale my stl file.

I tried few ways to do it, like kivy or pygame, but I still don't know which one it's the best choice.
Kivy has a good GUI and you can upload obj, but I couldn't find a way to connect **numpy-stl**, the stl file when is added at the scene give this error:

```
 <stl.mesh.Mesh object at 0x0C524570>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Nadia\Desktop\cube.py", line 56, in <module>
     My3DApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Nadia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "C:\Users\Nadia\Desktop\cube.py", line 48, in build
     self.renderer.render(scene, self.camera)
   File "C:\Users\Nadia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\kivy3\renderer.py", line 101, in render
     self._instructions.add(scene.as_instructions())
   File "C:\Users\Nadia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\kivy3\scenes\scene.py", line 36, in as_instructions
     for child in self.get_children_instructions():
   File "C:\Users\Nadia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\kivy3\core\object3d.py", line 154, in get_children_instructions
     yield child.as_instructions()
 **AttributeError: 'Mesh' object has no attribute 'as_instructions'**
>>>
```

This is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy3 import Renderer, Scene
from kivy3 import PerspectiveCamera
from kivy3.extras.geometries import BoxGeometry
from kivy3.core.geometry import Geometry
from kivy3 import Material, Mesh
import numpy
from stl import mesh


class My3DApp(App):
def _adjust_aspect(self, *args):
   rsize = self.renderer.size
   aspect = rsize[0] / float(rsize[1])
   self.renderer.camera.aspect = aspect

def rotate_cube(self, *dt):
    self.cube.rotation.y += 1


def build(self):
    layout = FloatLayout()
    self.renderer = Renderer()
    scene = Scene()

    cube_geo = BoxGeometry(1,1,1) 
    cube_mat = Material()
    self.cube = Mesh(
        geometry = cube_geo,
        material=cube_mat
        )
    self.cube.pos.z = -5
    
    self.stlfile = mesh.Mesh.from_file('exStl/test01.STL')
    print(self.stlfile)

    self.camera = PerspectiveCamera(
        fov=75,
        aspect = 0,
        near=1,
        far=10
        )

    scene.add(self.stlfile)
    
    scene.add(self.cube)
    self.renderer.render(scene, self.camera)
    self.renderer.bind(size=self._adjust_aspect)
    layout.add_widget(self.renderer)
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.rotate_cube, .01)
    #layout.add_widget(Builder.load_string(kv))
    return layout

if __name__=="__main__":
    My3DApp().run()
```

With Pygame I didn't have a lot of success either because it's quite complicate work on a stl, but I'm very ignorant about it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kivy itself can do what you want, but it isn't directly supported functionality and you would need to manage some parts of it yourself. It looks like you're trying Kivy3, which should do most of it, but I don't know if it directly supports STL files - you'll need to read its code for that.

In general, you should also be able to turn your STL file into an object that kivy3 can use by manually extracting the mesh information (at least the vertices and indices) and turning them into a kivy3 Mesh.